# Django's verbatim template tag does not prevent character escaping

Tags: django, django-templates, underscore.js

I am using Django's built in templating system, as well as Underscore.js'. Therefore, I need Django to leave alone the special chars which Underscore recognizes and renders.

I have checked the version of django, it is 1.5.3.

A very simple example:

```
{% verbatim %}
   <%= content %>
{% endverbatim %}
```

However, when I view this in the browser, the source code still shows:

```
&lt;%= content %&gt;
```

Obviously, when Underscore gets a hold of the HTML, it has no work to do since it can't find the proper tags to parse. I've already tried a couple troubleshooting solutions, none of which have worked:

1. Misspelling 'verbatim' causes an error, leading me to believe that Django's template engine is recognizing the tag.
2. Checking the django version. With 'import django; django.VERSION' I get 1.5.3.
3. Using the {% autoescape off %} tag, which similarly did not work (perhaps a related problem).

Here is the complete text of my template in case that lends any further clues. All of the tags besides {% verbatim %} perform the tasks they ought to.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{# Determine which navigation element is 'active'  #}
{% block nav %}
    {% with 'active' as lessons_active %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-md-2 lesson-left-menu">
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back to Lessons</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 lesson-container">

        <div class="slide multi-slide">
            <div class="lesson-header">
                {% verbatim %}
                    <h3><%= moduleTitle  %> <small><%= title %></small></h3>
                {% endverbatim %}
            </div>

            <!-- Populate dyn. based on # slides in lesson -->
            {% spaceless %}
                <div class="lesson-progress">
                    <div class="bar complete" style="width: 20%"></div>
                    <div class="bar complete" style="width: 20%"></div>
                    <div class="bar" style="width: 20%"></div>
                    <div class="bar" style="width: 20%"></div>
                    <div class="bar" style="width: 20%"></div>
                </div>
            {% endspaceless %}

            {% verbatim %}
                <%= content %>
            {% endverbatim %}

            <div class="well">
                <ul class="answers short-multi greek-text" style="min-height: 40px">
                </ul>
            </div>

            {% spaceless %}
                {% verbatim %}
                <% _.each(options, function(optionSet) { %>
                    <ul class="options short-multi greek-text inline">

                        <% _.each(optionSet, function(option) { %>
                            <li><a href="#" data-value="<%= option.value  %>"><%= option.display %></a></li>
                        <% }); %>

                    </ul>
                <% }); %>
                {% endverbatim %}
            {% endspaceless %}

        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: verbatim is only relevant in situations where Django template syntax shouldn't be parsed, thus `{{...}}` and `{%...%}`. In this case you have `<%...%>` which isn't Django template syntax. So something else is bothering you. You might want to have a look at Middleware, as those could be doing some unwanted content modification.

Comment: @bouke I see what you mean. I have also tried `{% autoescape off %}` and `{{ "<%= %>" | safe }}` in the same locations I have `{% verbatim %}` and that didn't solve the problem either. I don't think anything is happening Middleware-wise, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried it without wrapping the code in these blocks(I know this is a stretch).

In your case you shouldn't have to do anything to make this render correctly. I have the same setup in a Django Project of mine.

You shouldn't have to turn `{% autoescape off %}` unless you are injecting text into the page (via a variable or something) and you shouldn't have to use `{% Verbatim %}` unless you want to ignore django tags.